# Where is this "Projects and Interests" Section?

Tags: support, developer-story

so i thought i'd check what my developer story looked like in it's current state. obviously empty as expected.

then i wanted to see if anything would happen if saved my empty developer story to .pdf. it did download but inside it was this

[image: pdf]

a quick look on both developer story views and my settings showed no "Projects and Interests" section. Where is this "Projects and Interests" Section? shouldn't it (or the equivalent) be visible on either developer story view even if the Stack Overflow part isn't removable?

Answer (score 1):

You have a top tag on your Developer Story which is being added to the Projects & Interests section on the PDF. Any networks or tags you add your Developer Story will display here, in addition to your open source projects and apps.

You can remove the tag by editing the header of your Developer Story.